# Cards under CrystalLive™ Color are not the same size as the rest

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

The three cards under CrystalLive™ Color are not the same as the rest. Also I want to center this text: CrystalLive™ 2D, CrystalLive™ 3D, CrystalLive™ Color, CrystalLive™ Color, Crystal Clear Cycle™, so it goes right above the cards. It's my first ever website and I'm learning a lot from it. I know my error is probably somewhere in the 's but I've been searching for hours and can't find it. I would be really grateful if someone helps me out. Note: The CSS is all good, so the errors aren't there.

```
<div class="container">

 <div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4 mb-5">
<h2>HERA I10 Спецификации:</h2>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- /.row -->


<div class="how-section1">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 how-img">
                        <img src="img\crystalarchitecture.png" class="rounded-circle img-fluid" alt=""/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <h4>Crystal Architecture™</h4>
                                    <h4 class="subheading">Crystal 
Architecture™, an imaging architecture that combines CrystalBeam™ and 
  CrystalLive™, based on S-Vue Transducer™,
  is to provide crystal clear image. </h4>
                    <p class="text-muted">- CrystalBeam™ is a new 
       beamforming technology beneficial in delivering high-quality image 
       resolution and increased uniformity of images.
      <br>- CrystalLive™ is Samsung’s up-to-date ultrasound imaging 
       engine with enhanced 2D image processing, 3D rendering and color 
       signal processing,
            to offer outstanding image performance and efficient workflow during complex cases.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <h4>CrystalBeam™</h4>
                                    <h4 class="subheading">A New 
     Beamforming for In-depth Image Creation</h4>
                                    <p class="text-muted">CrystalBeam™ 
      utilizes Arbitrary Waveform Transmission, Massive Parallel 
      Beamforming and Synthetic Aperture technologies to produce a faster 
     frame rate and improved image uniformity.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 how-img">
                        <img src="img\crystalbeam.png" class="img-fluid" alt=""/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 how-img">

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <h4>CrystalLive™ 2D</h4>
                                    <h4 class="subheading">Sophisticated 
       2D Images Processed by CrystalLive™</h4>
                                    <p class="text-muted">CrystalLive™ 
       helps you to make more confident diagnoses with fundamental 2D 
         images.
          Some major advantages of 2D images include shadow-suppressed 
           images, lessened halo artifacts, and mitigated blurred area. 
                  </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <div class="card-group">

             <div class="col-md-4 mb-5">
          <div class="card h-100 text-center" >
           <img class="card-img-top " src="img\shadowhdr.png" alt="" />
      <div class="card-body">
    <h4 class="card-title"></h4>
    <p class="card-text">ShadowHDR™ selectively applies high-frequency 
        and low-frequency of the ultrasound to identify shadow areas such 
          as fetal head or spine where attenuation occurs.</p>
  </div>

</div>
    </div>
       <div class="col-md-4 mb-5">
     <div class="card h-100 text-center">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="img\hqvision.png" alt="" />
  <div class="card-body">
    <h4 class="card-title"></h4>
    <p class="card-text">HQ-Vision™ provides clearer images by mitigating 
        the characteristics of ultrasound images that are slightly 
          blurred than the actual vision.</p>
        </div>

     </div>
      </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 mb-5">
         <div class="card h-100 text-center">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="img\clearvision.png" alt="" />
  <div class="card-body">
    <h4 class="card-title"></h4>
    <p class="card-text">ClearVision provides clearer tissue boundaries 
        using the noise reduction filter and generates sharp 2D images. 
            It reduces halo artifact that occurs when the tissue contour 
           is enhanced, and removes noises on the tissue boundaries.</p>
  </div>

          </div>
          </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <h4>CrystalLive™ 3D</h4>
                                    <h4 class="subheading">Realistic 
         Description of 3D/4D Performance</h4>
                                    <p class="text-muted">CrystalLive™ in 
         3D/4D provides users with more realistic and high-resolution 
             images.
          <br>It outdoes conventional 3D imaging technologies in terms of 
                viewing small parts and lighting effects.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 how-img">

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-group">

      <div class="col-md-4 mb-5">
         <div class="card h-100 text-center" >
         <img class="card-img-top " src="img\crystalvue.png" alt="" />
             <div class="card-body">
    <h4 class="card-title"></h4>
    <p class="card-text">CrystalVue™ is an advanced volume rendering 
           technology that enhances visualization of both internal and 
         external structures in a single rendered image using a 
            combination of intensity, gradient and position.<br>*Optional 
             Extra</p>
       </div>

        </div>
          </div>
         <div class="col-md-4 mb-5">
           <div class="card h-100 text-center">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="img\realisticvue.png" alt="" />
          <div class="card-body">
         <h4 class="card-title"></h4>
      <p class="card-text">RealisticVue™ displays high resolution 3D 
        anatomy with exceptional detail and realistic depth perception. 
           User selectable light source direction creates intricately 
           graduated shadows for better defined anatomical structures. 
          <br>*Optional Extra</p>
  </div>

     </div>
     </div>
         <div class="col-md-4 mb-5">
          <div class="card h-100 text-center">
         <img class="card-img-top" src="img\hdvi.png" alt="" />
        <div class="card-body">
          <h4 class="card-title"></h4>
              <p class="card-text">HDVI™ is a volume rendering technology 
      that improves visualization of edges and small structures in volume 
          data. Upgraded marginal expression and image saturation 
        expresses the very details from angle to shadow of the fetus.</p>
           </div>

        </div>
      </div>
          </div>
                </div>

            <div class="how-section1">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 how-img">

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <h4>CrystalLive™ Color</h4>
                                    <h4 class="subheading">Detailed 
         Expression of Blood Flow Dynamics</h4>
                <p class="text-muted">Color performance of 
         CrystalLive™ has been improved to clearly visualize the 
         hemodynamics of the blood flow. Greater sensitivity resulting 
            from new color signal processing allows for a more accurate 
            detection of peripheral blood vessels, microcirculatory blood 
            flows, and volumes of slow blood flows.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                                    <div class="card-group">

       <div class="col-md-4 mb-5">
      <div class="card h-100 text-center" >
     <img class="card-img-top " src="img\lumiflow.png" alt="" />
     <div class="card-body">
     <h4 class="card-title"></h4>
      <p class="card-text">LumiFlow™ is a three-dimensional visualization 
     of blood flow, which helps to understand the structure of blood flow 
      and small vessels intuitively.<br>*Optional Extra</p>
     </div>

    </div>
   </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 mb-5">
     <div class="card h-100 text-center">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="img\mv-flow.png" alt="" />
      <div class="card-body">
       <h4 class="card-title"></h4>
       <p class="card-text">MV-Flow™ offers a novel alternative to power 
  Doppler for visualizing slow flow of microvascularized structures. High 
   frame rates and advanced filtering enable MV-Flow™ to provide a 
   detailed view of blood flow in relation to surrounding tissue or 
   pathology with enhanced spatial resolution.<br>*Optional Extra</p>
  </div>

    </div>
    </div>
     <div class="col-md-4 mb-5">
     <div class="card h-100 text-center">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="img\s-flow.png" alt="" />
        <div class="card-body">
       <h4 class="card-title"></h4>
           <p class="card-text">S-Flow™, a directional Power Doppler 
      imaging technology, can help to detect even the peripheral blood 
      vessels. It enables accurate diagnosis when blood flow examination 
     is especially difficult.</p>
     </div>

   </div>
   </div>
    </div>
   </div>



                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <h4>Crystal Clear Cycle™</h4>
                                    <h4 class="subheading">Samsung’s 
      Commitment to Life-Long Healthcare for Women</h4>
                                    <p class="text-muted">Crystal Clear 
 Cycle™, an integrated solution for women’s health issues, represents 
 Samsung’s commitment to ensuring life-long healthcare for women. The 
  Crystal Clear Cycle™ categorizes the most significant health events for 
 women into six stages and provides effective diagnostic solutions at 
 each stage.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 how-img">

                    </div>
                </div> 
                                    <div class="card-group">

   <div class="col-md-4 mb-5">
   <div class="card h-100 text-center" >
     <img class="card-img-top " src="img\biometryassist.png" alt="" />
       <div class="card-body">
    <h4 class="card-title"></h4>
    <p class="card-text">A semi-automatic technology for biometric 
 measurement, BiometryAssist™, enables users to measure the growth of the 
fetus more quickly and with greater accuracy while maintaining exam 
   consistency.</p>
  </div>

   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 mb-5">
  <div class="card h-100 text-center">
     <img class="card-img-top" src="img\5dcns.png" alt="" />
    <div class="card-body">
      <h4 class="card-title"></h4>
    <p class="card-text">5D CNS+™ uses intelligent navigation to provide 
          6 measurements from 3 transverse views of the fetal brain to 
        enhance measurement reproducibility and streamline workflow. 
          <br>*Optional Extra</p>
     </div>

       </div>
       </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 mb-5">
<div class="card h-100 text-center">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="img\5dlimb.png" alt="" />
  <div class="card-body">
    <h4 class="card-title"></h4>
    <p class="card-text">5D Limb Vol.™ is a semi-automated tool to 
        quickly and accurately measure upper arm or thigh volumes from 3 
          simple seed points on a single volume data set.<br>*Optional Extra</p>
     </div>

   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: do you mean color of the text in the cards is not same as the color of other text ?

Answer (score 0):

is this what you are looking to achieve ?

```html
<link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />

<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 mb-5">
      <h2>HERA I10 Спецификации:</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /.row -->


<div class="how-section1">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 how-img">
      <img src="img\crystalarchitecture.png" class="rounded-circle img-fluid" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h4 class="text-center">Crystal Architecture™</h4>
      <h4 class="subheading">Crystal Architecture™, an imaging architecture that combines CrystalBeam™ and CrystalLive™, based on S-Vue Transducer™, is to provide crystal clear image. </h4>
      <p class="text-muted">- CrystalBeam™ is a new beamforming technology beneficial in delivering high-quality image resolution and increased uniformity of images.
        <br>- CrystalLive™ is Samsung’s up-to-date ultrasound imaging engine with enhanced 2D image processing, 3D rendering and color signal processing, to offer outstanding image performance and efficient workflow during complex cases.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h4 class="text-center">CrystalBeam™</h4>
      <h4 class="subheading">A New Beamforming for In-depth Image Creation</h4>
      <p class="text-muted">CrystalBeam™ utilizes Arbitrary Waveform Transmission, Massive Parallel Beamforming and Synthetic Aperture technologies to produce a faster frame rate and improved image uniformity.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 how-img">
      <img src="img\crystalbeam.png" class="img-fluid" alt="" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 how-img">

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h4 class="text-center">CrystalLive™ 2D</h4>
      <h4 class="subheading">Sophisticated 2D Images Processed by CrystalLive™</h4>
      <p class="text-muted">CrystalLive™ helps you to make more confident diagnoses with fundamental 2D images. Some major advantages of 2D images include shadow-suppressed images, lessened halo artifacts, and mitigated blurred area.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-group">

    <div class="col-md-4 mb-5">
      <div class="card h-100 text-center">
        <img class="card-img-top " src="img\shadowhdr.png" alt="" />
        <div class="card-body">
          <h4 class="card-title"></h4>
          <p class="card-text text-muted">ShadowHDR™ selectively applies high-frequency and low-frequency of the ultrasound to identify shadow areas such as fetal head or spine where attenuation occurs.</p>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 mb-5">
      <div class="card h-100 text-center">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="img\hqvision.png" alt="" />
        <div class="card-body">
          <h4 class="card-title"></h4>
          <p class="card-text text-muted">HQ-Vision™ provides clearer images by mitigating the characteristics of ultrasound images that are slightly blurred than the actual vision.</p>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 mb-5">
      <div class="card h-100 text-center">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="img\clearvision.png" alt="" />
        <div class="card-body">
          <h4 class="card-title"></h4>
          <p class="card-text text-muted">ClearVision provides clearer tissue boundaries using the noise reduction filter and generates sharp 2D images. It reduces halo artifact that occurs when the tissue contour is enhanced, and removes noises on the tissue boundaries.</p>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h4 class="text-center">CrystalLive™ 3D</h4>
        <h4 class="subheading">Realistic Description of 3D/4D Performance</h4>
        <p class="text-muted">CrystalLive™ in 3D/4D provides users with more realistic and high-resolution images.
          <br>It outdoes conventional 3D imaging technologies in terms of viewing small parts and lighting effects.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 how-img">

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-group">

      <div class="col-md-4 mb-5">
        <div class="card h-100 text-center">
          <img class="card-img-top " src="img\crystalvue.png" alt="" />
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title"></h4>
            <p class="card-text text-muted">CrystalVue™ is an advanced volume rendering technology that enhances visualization of both internal and external structures in a single rendered image using a combination of intensity, gradient and position.<br>*Optional Extra
            </p>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 mb-5">
        <div class="card h-100 text-center">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="img\realisticvue.png" alt="" />
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title"></h4>
            <p class="card-text text-muted">RealisticVue™ displays high resolution 3D anatomy with exceptional detail and realistic depth perception. User selectable light source direction creates intricately graduated shadows for better defined anatomical structures.
              <br>*Optional Extra</p>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 mb-5">
        <div class="card h-100 text-center">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="img\hdvi.png" alt="" />
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title"></h4>
            <p class="card-text text-muted">HDVI™ is a volume rendering technology that improves visualization of edges and small structures in volume data. Upgraded marginal expression and image saturation expresses the very details from angle to shadow of the fetus.</p>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="how-section1">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 how-img">

      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h4 class="text-center">CrystalLive™ Color</h4>
        <h4 class="subheading">Detailed Expression of Blood Flow Dynamics</h4>
        <p class="text-muted">Color performance of CrystalLive™ has been improved to clearly visualize the hemodynamics of the blood flow. Greater sensitivity resulting from new color signal processing allows for a more accurate detection of peripheral blood vessels, microcirculatory
          blood flows, and volumes of slow blood flows.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-group">

      <div class="col-md-4 mb-5">
        <div class="card h-100 text-center">
          <img class="card-img-top " src="img\lumiflow.png" alt="" />
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title"></h4>
            <p class="card-text text-muted">LumiFlow™ is a three-dimensional visualization of blood flow, which helps to understand the structure of blood flow and small vessels intuitively.<br>*Optional Extra</p>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 mb-5">
        <div class="card h-100 text-center">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="img\mv-flow.png" alt="" />
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title"></h4>
            <p class="card-text text-muted">MV-Flow™ offers a novel alternative to power Doppler for visualizing slow flow of microvascularized structures. High frame rates and advanced filtering enable MV-Flow™ to provide a detailed view of blood flow in relation to surrounding tissue
              or pathology with enhanced spatial resolution.<br>*Optional Extra</p>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 mb-5">
        <div class="card h-100 text-center">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="img\s-flow.png" alt="" />
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title"></h4>
            <p class="card-text text-muted">S-Flow™, a directional Power Doppler imaging technology, can help to detect even the peripheral blood vessels. It enables accurate diagnosis when blood flow examination is especially difficult.</p>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h4 class="text-center">Crystal Clear Cycle™</h4>
      <h4 class="subheading">Samsung’s Commitment to Life-Long Healthcare for Women</h4>
      <p class="text-muted">Crystal Clear Cycle™, an integrated solution for women’s health issues, represents Samsung’s commitment to ensuring life-long healthcare for women. The Crystal Clear Cycle™ categorizes the most significant health events for women into six stages
        and provides effective diagnostic solutions at each stage.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 how-img">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-group">

    <div class="col-md-4 mb-5">
      <div class="card h-100 text-center">
        <img class="card-img-top " src="img\biometryassist.png" alt="" />
        <div class="card-body">
          <h4 class="card-title"></h4>
          <p class="card-text text-muted">A semi-automatic technology for biometric measurement, BiometryAssist™, enables users to measure the growth of the fetus more quickly and with greater accuracy while maintaining exam consistency.
          </p>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 mb-5">
      <div class="card h-100 text-center">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="img\5dcns.png" alt="" />
        <div class="card-body">
          <h4 class="card-title"></h4>
          <p class="card-text text-muted">5D CNS+™ uses intelligent navigation to provide 6 measurements from 3 transverse views of the fetal brain to enhance measurement reproducibility and streamline workflow.
            <br>*Optional Extra</p>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 mb-5">
      <div class="card h-100 text-center">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="img\5dlimb.png" alt="" />
        <div class="card-body">
          <h4 class="card-title"></h4>
          <p class="card-text text-muted">5D Limb Vol.™ is a semi-automated tool to quickly and accurately measure upper arm or thigh volumes from 3 simple seed points on a single volume data set.<br>*Optional Extra</p>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This didnt fix the issue, but thanks anyway. The cards under CrystalLive™ Color are still smaller than the rest.  Also the text isnt aligned in center

https://i.imgur.com/IPw41hO.png
    .how-section1{
    margin-top:-15%;
    padding: 10%;
    }
    .how-section1 h4{
    color: #25c4e2;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 35px;
    }
    .how-section1 .subheading{
    color: #3931af;
    font-size: 25px;
    }
    .how-section1 .row
    {
    margin-top: 10%;
    }
    .how-img 
    {
    text-align: center;
    }
    .how-img img{
     }